# Using OpenGL in my android application to create a map of an indoor location

Tags: android, opengl-es, indoor-positioning-system

I am building an android application for indoor localization, and want to add a map functionality allowing the user to see its current location in a particular floor. Is using OpenGL to draw the shapes of the map and provide the "navigation" by having the map respond to touch events for example a good solution? Is there an easier solution considering that I have no prior knowledge of OpenGL?

Comment: If you are using android, you'll have to use OpenGL-ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for Open GL for android. You could use this tutorial to start your work:
https://developer.android.com/training/building-graphics.html

Hope this helps!